Why did my local Git repository get damaged when I changed my system from Ubuntu 22.04 to Windows 10
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 (Linux-to-go) and Windows 10 on my desktop.
Everything was working fine until I reinstalled Windows 10 on a new SSD (because my previous system SSD had developed bad blocks).
The Git repository in question is located on a separate SSD that both Ubuntu and Windows can access. The file system on the SSD is NTFS.
situations
The first time:
I left some changes uncommitted in the repository before shutting down Ubuntu and rebooting into Windows.
When I checked the repository in Windows, I encountered this error:
$ git status
error:bad signature x00000000
fatal: index file corrupt

(I managed to fix it by deleting the .git/index file and restoring it.)
Also,
I noticed other strange behavior, such as one of my .md files being completely corrupted
(its content was replaced with something resembling binary data).
Windows 10 also reported an issue with the drive, though I'm a bit fuzzy on the details.
The second time:
This time I was more careful. I committed all changes and unmounted the SSD before switching to Windows. However, this time I got a different error:
$ git status
fatal: bad object HEAD

problems
What could be causing these issues? It's frustrating not being able to manage projects smoothly across the two operating systems.
Thanks!

progress
After using Windows 10 for a little over a day, a notification suddenly popped up saying 'Restart your computer to repair drive errors.' I chose to restart later. After a while, I checked the Git directory again and found that git status was working, but the repository had reverted to the commit from the last time I used Windows 10.
So I copied the second commit ID from the last line in .git/logs/refs/heads/<target branch name> (the one that was committed in Ubuntu and was still there) and replaced the content in .git/refs/heads/<target branch name> with it. After doing this, everything appeared normal again.
(This is strange. Did the system perform some kind of repair on the Git repository? What did they do?)

Oh, the command I typed in Windows 10 was through wsl2 (Ubuntu22.04)
